# Restart a "failed to start" build on another agent

Tags: teamcity

Occasionally, one of my Windows build agents will get a "failed to start" message because it was unable to clean up the checkout directory from a previous build. This is usually because an MSBuild process is still hanging on to a file handle.

```
[Updating sources] Failed to perform checkout on agent: '"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" clean -f -d -x' command failed.
exit code: 1
stdout: Removing bin/
[...]
stderr: warning: failed to remove bin/prod/otherDirectory
warning: failed to remove bin/prod/yetAnotherDirectory
```

One solution to this is to use Swabra to kill the process before the next build starts, as [described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31243840/191521).

Another thing I'd like to try is to automatically re-add the "failed to start" build to the queue and force it to run on another agent. The problem agent usually resolves itself within a few minutes, so kicking off the build immediately on another agent is a good temporary solution.

Is it possible to add "failed to start" builds to the queue again in this manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TeamCity has a [Retry Build Trigger](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Configuring+Build+Triggers) that satisfies my requirements. It doesn't allow specifying an agent to run the build on, but the "Seconds to wait" parameter and the nature of my build queue mitigate that.

[image: Retry Build Trigger UI, TeamCity 10.0.5]

Answer (score 0):

Was the question about how to manually specify on which agent to run a build? If so then there is *Custom Build* feature, which allows you to select desired agent from dropdown. Just click "..." button next to "Run".

Comment: I want to queue a new build automatically when the build fails to start, rather than manually starting a specific build from the UI.